# Microsoft TTS (Text to Speech) Dat File Locations

Tags: text-to-speech, sapi

Ok, so I've downloaded some TTS engines to replace the default microsoft TTS engine, and make my program sound a little more 'human' -- basically i am wondering where abouts the TTS engine files are stored on the local pc (windows 7)

-- the files i have are in .Dat format, does anyone have any idea where abouts the should go to be registered as a voice for Text-to-Speech?

Cheers.

**@UPDATE:**
Ok, after searching thru the registry, i see i need to create a new registry key & values for the dat file and where abouts the file is located, format(s), etc ... i have it registering as a Text-To-Speech Voice now, but when i try and load it i get the following error: "This voice cannot be played. Please try selecting another voice or selecting a different audio output device." -- any ideas? -- is there any ways to check the encoding of the DAT files i have downloaded?

Comment: Which engines are you trying to use?  Typically the installer creates the regkeys.  There are more regkeys than you might think, particularly for a 3rd party voice.

Comment: AT&T, Neospeech, and a few others...

Comment: AT&T voices in particular have their own TTS engine that has to be installed.  It's not just a new set of data files; there's an entirely different TTS engine.  

The last time I used the AT&T voices, there was an installer that did all the setup.  Have you tried running that?

I also assume that Neospeech has its own engine that needs installation as well.